# Prevent DataView retrieving old data after it has been updated

Tags: java, wicket

I've been having some problems with DataView that always retrieve the old data set. Even though the page has been re-loaded, IDataProvider has never been updated into the current state of the database. Here is how my IDataProvider looks like :

```
   private class MyDataProvider implements IDataProvider<Item> {

    private List<Item> list;

    private List<Item> getData() {
        if(list == null) {
            list = projectLogic.getItems();
            Collections.reverse(list);
        }
        return list;
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<Item> iterator(int first, int count){
        return getData().subList(first, first + count).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size(){
        return getData().size();
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<Item> model(Item object){
        return new DetachableItemModel(object);
    }

    /**
     * Detaches model after use. This is generally used to null out transient references that can be re-attached later. 
     */
    @Override
    public void detach(){
        list = null;
    }

}
```

detach() is already set the list into null but why does this not affect the provider in my dataview?

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me.

Does projectLogic access the db every time? Did you put a breakpoint on getData()?

Comment: I tested it and projectLogic access the db every time. What do you mean by "a breakpoint"?